# Safely unwrap consecutively

Tags: if-statement, rust

I have an `if` statement which needs to check for the existence of a value in a nested `Option`. The statement currently looks like

```rust
if my_vec.get(0).is_some() && my_vec.get(0).unwrap().is_some() {      
    // My True Case
} else {
    // My Else Case
}
```

I feel like this is an amateurish way of checking if this potential nested value exists. I want to maintain safety when fetching the `Option` from the array as it may or may not exist, and also when unwrapping the `Option` itself. I tried using `and_then` and similar operators but haven't had any luck.

Comment: `if let Some(Some(_)) = my_vec.get(0) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check the length first and access it like a regular array instead of using `.get(x)` unless there is some benefit in doing so (like passing it to something which expects an option).

```rust
if my_vec.len() > x && my_vec[x].is_some() {
    // etc
}
```

Another option is to just match the value with an `if let x = y` or full `match` statement.

```rust
if let Some(Some(_)) = my_vec.get(x) {
    // etc
}
```

The `matches!` macro can also be used in this situation similarly to the `if let` when you don't need to take a reference to the data.

```rust
if matches!(my_vec.get(x), Some(Some(_))) {
    // etc
}
```

Or the `and_then` version, but personally it is probably my least favorite since it is longer and gargles the intention.

```rust
if my_vec.get(x).and_then(|y| y.as_ref()).is_some() {
    // etc
}
```

You can pick whichever one is your favorite. They all compile down to the same thing (probably, I haven't checked).

Comment: I disagree on the first point -- the whole reason `.get()` returns an `Option` is precisely so you _don't have to_ check the length first. Pattern matching is definitely the right way to do this.